# How do I implement simulated frames in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

How do I implement a simulated frameset in ASP.NET MVC without running afoul of browser differences?

If possible, I would like a header and two vertical panes.  The header will be pinned to the top of the browser.  The left pane will contain an index of some sort, and the right frame will contain content.  Each of these panes can have its own scrollbar, but only if the content is long enough to require it.

It should look similar to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(loband).aspx

NOTE: I do not need to support IE6, but I do need to support IE7 for awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the jQuery splitter plugin.

http://methvin.com/splitter/

Comment: Ultimately this is what I decided to use.  It does a better job of abstracting away the browser differences than CSS templates do, and it handles the scrollbars flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Layouts. Some examples: http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

Comment: The scrolling can be added to the divs using CSS.

Comment: I experimented with CSS templates for awhile, but I was never able to get the scrollbars to do what I wanted.